# R - Subset a Dataframe with a Programmatically built Formula

Tags: r, filter, subset

I'm working with a large data frame that is pulled from a data lake which I need to subset according to multiple different columns and run an analysis on. The basic subsettings come from an external Excel file which I read in and generate all possible combinations of. I want something to loop through each of these columns and subset my data accordingly.

A few of the subsettings follow a similar form to:

```
data_settings <- data.frame(country = rep(c('DE','RU','US','CA','BR'),6), 
                            transport=rep(c('road','air','sea')),
                            category = rep(c('A','B')))
```

And my data lake extract has a form like:

```
df <- data.frame(country = rep(unique(data_settings$country),6), 
                 transport = rep(unique(data_settings$transport),10),
                 category = rep(c('A','B'),15), 
                 values = round(runif(30) * 10))
```

I need to subset the data according to each of the rows in my `data_settings` data frame, so I built a loop which constructs the formula according to what is in my `data_settings` data frame.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data_settings)){
  sub_string <- paste0(names(data_settings[1]), '==', data_settings[i,1])
  for(j in 2:ncol(data_settings)){
    col <- names(data_settings)[j]
    val <- as.character(data_settings[i,j])
    sub_string <- paste0(sub_string, ' & ', col," == ","'",val,"'")
  }
  df_sub <- subset(df, formula(sub_string))
}
```

This successfully builds my strings which I try to pass to `formula` or `as.formula`, but I receive an error at that point. I've tried a few different formulations without any success. In my actual case, there are thousands of combinations with different columns and values to filter against.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
merge(data_settings, df)
```

Comment: It works in a way I hadn't even considered before, but it is a bit slower than expected.

Comment: You could try data.table's merge to see if it is any faster:  `library(data.table); merge(data.table(data_settings, key = names(data_settings)), df)`

Answer (score 0):

I worked with my previous approach a bit more today without using `subset`, `filter`, etc. and put this together which seems to do what I want well enough by filtering recursively according to the next item in the `data_settings` frame.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data_settings)){
  df_sub <- df
  for(j in 1:ncol(data_settings)){
    col <- names(data_settings)[j]
    val <- as.character(data_settings[i,j])
    df_col <- grep(col, names(df))
    df_sub <- df_sub[df_sub[,df_col] == val,]
  }
  # Run further analysis here...

}
```